# CorePlot YAxis with two types of Scaling

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is it possible to achieve different scaling for positive part of Y-axis and different scaling for its negative part of Y-axis.The idea is to show most part of plot area for positive values and less part for negative values.

Comment: What do you mean by "scaling"?

Comment: @EricSkroch by scaling I meant if I have 100% plot area then out of that only 20% to be used for negative values plotting irrespective of the value's magnitutude.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `yRange` of the plot space so that 20% of the range is negative. For example, a range with a `location` of -25 and `length` of 125 meets this requirement.